# How to read in directory name as user input, without double backslashes?

Tags: r, windows, input, paste, backslash

I want to write generic code which takes input from user, but when I run:

> directory_name <- readline(prompt=" Enter the directory")

Enter the directory `C:\Users\ANKIT\Documents`

It shows directory name like this (with double-backslashes)

directory_name "C:\\Users\\ANKIT\\Documents"

And how to use this directory name to load .csv file?

Comment: You can use `paste(directory_name, "\\youfile.csv")` and then with `read.csv` read the data

Comment: but directory name is coming like this 
C:\\Users\\ANKIT\\Document

Comment: If it is windows, it should work

Comment: It should be `paste0`

Comment: There are many prior duplicates of this question, but they're terribly titled and tagged. Please help clean up and retag them. Then close this as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Use read.csv and paste0:

```
directory_name <- readline(prompt=" Enter the directory")
```

> Enter *C:\Users\griffinevo\temporaryRfiles*

```
read.csv(paste0(directory_name, "\\filename.csv"))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `paste0` to `paste` the file with the object `directory_name`

```
directory_name <- readline(prompt=" Enter the directory")
dat <- read.csv(paste0(directory_name, "\\mpg_data.csv"))
```

Or with `paste` and specify the `sep`

```
dat <- read.csv(paste(directory_name, "mpg_data.csv", sep="\\")) 
dim(dat)
#[1] 79 16
```